# Does any animate events fire when element is removed?

Tags: jquery

I have

```
 $("#sDiv").animate({ marginTop: "100px" }, 10000);
```

if I click a button to remove the Div in the middle of its animation does any events fire?

```
 $("#btn1").click(function () {
    $("#sDiv").remove();
 });
```

Comment: What events are you referring to???

Comment: What do you mean? You want to be able to know when an element is removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe somethig like this ?

```
var m = false;
$("#sDiv").animate({ marginTop: "100px" }, 10000, function() {
    m = true;
});   

$("#btn1").click(function () {
    if(m) $("#sDiv").remove();
});
```

Comment: You triggered an idea in my head. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the `div` **after** animating it, you have to use the `animate` method in the click function and you have use the callback to remove the `div`, like this :

```
$("#btn1").click(function () {
    $("#sDiv").animate({ marginTop: "100px" }, 10000, function() {
      $("#sDiv").remove();
    });    
});
```

Or, I might've misunderstood the question. Please clarify if that's the case.

Comment: Yes - this is how you know when an animation has completed - but how is this related to the question?

Comment: I mightve misread the question. I presumed that OP wanted to remove the div after the animation was complete. I got it from this line : **in the middle of its animation does any events fire**